# Prevent script from running twice while being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a jquery/javascript carousel that I am using, however if the user clicks the right or left nav buttons multiple times before the script has finished executing it creates an ugly animation/screws up the order of the carousel.

Is there a way I can prevent this function from being called again (a quick second click) while it is still executing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.inner-main li:first').before($('.inner-main li:last'));
});

function mainSlide(direction) {
    var item_width = 940;

    if (direction == 'left') {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) + item_width;
    } else {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) - item_width;
    }

    $('.inner-main').animate({ 'left': movement }, 800, function () {
        if (direction == 'left') {
            $('.inner-main li:first').before($('.inner-main li:last'));
        } else {
            $('.inner-main li:last').after($('.inner-main li:first'));
        }
        $('.inner-main').css({ 'left': '-940px' });
    });
}
```

Comment: try putting .stop() before .animate()

Comment: tried that, doesnt work because when a user clicks it calls the function which has to do calculations (var item_width) so when the user clicks multiple times it keeps recalculating

Comment: ahh good point. I would try 59's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the element is not currently animating before running the animation again:

```
if(!$('.inner-main').is(':animated')) {
  // animation code
}
```

**Edit:**
Try queuing the calculation and animation so they don't execute until any other animations complete:

```
function mainSlide(direction) {
    $('.inner-main').queue( function() {
        var item_width = 940;

        if (direction == 'left') {
            var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) + item_width;
        } else {
            var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) - item_width;
        }

        $('.inner-main').animate({ 'left': movement }, 800, function () {
        if (direction == 'left') {
            $('.inner-main li:first').before($('.inner-main li:last'));
        } else {
            $('.inner-main li:last').after($('.inner-main li:first'));
        }
        $('.inner-main').css({ 'left': '-940px' });
    });
}
```

Comment: im not looking to prevent the animation, im looking to prevent the function from calculating twice and then displaying poorly

Comment: Ah, I see.  So if the left button is clicked twice, you would like the animation to finish once, and then immediately begin a second time?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: you were on the right track with :animated i found the correct answer posting below

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = false; 
function mainSlide(direction) {
if(!flag)
{
flag = true;
    var item_width = 940;

    if (direction == 'left') {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) + item_width;
    } else {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) - item_width;
    }

    $('.inner-main').animate({ 'left': movement }, 800, function () {
        if (direction == 'left') {
            $('.inner-main li:first').before($('.inner-main li:last'));
        } else {
            $('.inner-main li:last').after($('.inner-main li:first'));
        }
        $('.inner-main').css({ 'left': '-940px' });
    });
flag = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer, had to add :not(:animated) before the animate in order to prevent the animation from goin crazy on me

```
function mainSlide(direction) {
    var item_width = 940;

    if (direction == 'left') {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) + item_width;
    } else {
        var movement = parseInt($('.inner-main').css('left')) - item_width;
    }

    $('.inner-main:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left': movement }, 800, function () {
        if (direction == 'left') {
            $('.inner-main li:first').before($('.inner-main li:last'));
        } else {
            $('.inner-main li:last').after($('.inner-main li:first'));
        }
        $('.inner-main').css({ 'left': '-940px' });
    });
}
```